# ViewExpiredException when sending a POST request using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Sending POST request mostly gives this error:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
 <error>
  <error-name>
   class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
  </error-name>
  <error-message>
   <![CDATA[viewId:/user/searchstatus.xhtml - View /user/searchstatus.xhtml could not be restored.]]>
  </error-message>
 </error>
</partial-response>
```

What am just doing is, this site uses captcha to get vehicle information.So firstly am solving that captcha and then getting data. Most of the time above error is showing. Only a few times am getting the result and sometimes captcha mismatched occurs. 
Tried cache control as no cache if in case cache is causing problem.But still same.
Here is the code

````
app_url = 'https://vahan.nic.in/nrservices/faces/user/searchstatus.xhtml'





button = soup.find("button",{"type": "submit"})


encodedViewState = viewstate.replace("/", "%2F").replace("+", "%2B").replace("=", "%3D")


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Host': 'vahan.nic.in',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=%s; SERVERID_7081=vahanapi_7081; SERVERID_7082=nrservice_7082' % cookies['JSESSIONID'],
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Faces-Request':'partial/ajax',
    'Origin':'https://vahan.nic.in',
    'Referer':'https://vahan.nic.in/nrservices/faces/user/searchstatus.xhtml',
    'Connection':'keep-alive'

}

viewstate = soup.select('input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]')[0]['value']
data = {
    'javax.faces.partial.ajax':'true',
    'javax.faces.source': button['id'],
    'javax.faces.partial.execute':'@all',
    'javax.faces.partial.render': 'rcDetailsPanel resultPanel userMessages capatcha txt_ALPHA_NUMERIC',
    button['id']:button['id'],
    'masterLayout':'masterLayout',
    'regn_no1_exact': 'pb35n4655',
    'txt_ALPHA_NUMERIC': ans,
    'javax.faces.ViewState': viewstate,
    'j_idt42':''
}


postResponse = requests.post(url=app_url, data=data,headers=headers, cookies=cookies )


rsoup = BeautifulSoup(postResponse.text, 'html.parser')

print(rsoup.prettify())




    ```
````

Comment: Hi, have you got the solution??please let me know i am trying to do the same as you want, Please help me..

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: Yeah, I'm too stick here, please inform me when you got the solution.